# RN app does not build after expo-task-manager installation

Tags: android, react-native, expo

My app ran fine until the expo-task-manager installation. The IOS app builds and works as expected, tasks are created and work as they should. After getting IOS to work I switched to android but unfortunately the app doesn't build anymore.

`node_modules/react-native-unimodules/node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/android/src/main/java/org/unimodules/adapters/react/ReactAdapterPackage.java:29: error: cannot find symbol AppLoaderProvider.registerLoader(context, "react-native-headless", RNHeadlessAppLoader.class);`

The arrow to indicate the error is placed on the dot between AppLoaderProvider.registerLoader.

Reverting back to before the expo-task-manager was installed gets the app working 100% so the problem is directly related. The app is ejected btw.

I already updated react-native-unimodules but that was not the fix.

rn version; 0.62.2
expo-task-manager: 8.3.0
expo: 35.0.0
react-native-unimodules: ^0.9.1

Does anyone know how I can get the android app to build?

Comment: Same issue with     "react-native-unimodules": "^0.9.1", any updates @MarkT?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have removed expo-task-manager entirely and stopped developing the background tasks for now.

Comment: I somehow make it work by: `expo update` command.

Comment: Damn I didn't try that I think! Is your app ejected or are you still in a managed workflow?

Comment: Yes, I am using managed workflow

Answer (score 0):

Not the perfect answer, but `expo update` fixed my problem.